# How to execute a method with context of where it is called and not where it was defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a component which has very less dependencies and requires almost no extra code for using it inside another component. I'm stuck where i need to set the state because `setState` method requires `this` context.

Currently I'm sending `this`, as a context to the method defined in my Library Component.

```
export const showSnackbarNotification = (context, msg, variant) => {
  context.setState({
    [`notificationMsg`]: msg, 
    [`notificationToggle`]: true,
    [`variant`]: variant
  })
}
```

And I'm calling this function like below:

```
showSnackbarNotification(this, "checking the function", "error");
```

But I don't want the user to send `this` context via method parameter. Is there any way that i can execute the method with the context of where it is called. So `showSnackbarNotification` definition becomes:

```
export const showSnackbarNotification = (msg, variant) => {
  this.setState({
    [`notificationMsg`]: msg, 
    [`notificationToggle`]: true,
    [`variant`]: variant
  })
}
```

and still set the state of Component where i called `showSnackbarNotification` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular function:

```js
export function showSnackbarNotification(msg, variant) {
  this.setState({
    [`notificationMsg`]: msg, 
    [`notificationToggle`]: true,
    [`variant`]: variant
  })
}
```

when you call it you can use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to set the context:

```js
showSnackbarNotification.call(this, "checking the function", "error");
```

Arrow functions always have the context in which they are declared. Regular functions adopt the context in which they are called.

[Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable/34361380#34361380)

Comment: I tried that @Ross Allen, But this doesn't work. Error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
 `

Comment: @MaherShahmeer I updated my answer. When you call it, you can use `.call` to set the context.

Comment: I suggest seeing if a [higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) would suit your use case better though. The pattern you're using now is more like a "mixin", and they become difficult to understand in larger codebases; it's difficult to know what is controlling the state of a given component.

Comment: I understand @Ross Allen. Your updated answer worked for me now. I'll surely look into HOC right now. (y)